# ALL products are redirecting to 404 error in magento 2.0

Tags: magento2

When I click on products in home page of my website, it is redirecting to some error page i.e u have typed wrong url. I am using magento 2.0. I am getting same error for all products. How to resolve it?????

but all products are displayed in categories as well as home page

Comment: Check for the correct product url.You can compare the path when you redirect from category page and the path from home page.

Comment: both are same..products details are not displaying..

Comment: Can you please add your project links here?

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the following step to solve this problem.

step 1:- Please login and open a category.

Step 2:- Please assign a product.

step 3:- Then save that category.

Now all product will be working fine.

Comment: i imported some products through CSV files,if i add new product(manually)then also i am getting same error